# How do I upgrade the version of a maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven-2, build-process, maven-ear-plugin

I am using the maven-ear-plugin version 2.3.1 - I know there is a new version available: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/

I can't work out how to upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting the latest version?  maven will tend to do this for you automatically.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The default plugin versions are inherited from the Super POM, and you can check them with `mvn help:effective-pom`.

If you want to override the version provided there, add this to your POM:

```xml
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Replace the version with what you need.

Comment: What about in the case of plugins which are used from the command-line without any POM, such as maven-install-plugin? For example I tried to install a jar in my local repository by following these steps: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html
On the last paragraph they mention a cool feature from maven-install-plugin version 2.5, but whenever I run the command, maven-3.3.9 is using the version 2.4 of the plugin, even though I have also version 2.5.2 in the repo. I even tried to delete 2.4 from my repo, but maven re-dowloaded it. Where can I configure it?

Comment: Ok, I have found the answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155639/how-do-i-force-maven-to-use-maven-install-plugin-version-2-5

Answer (score 54):

Even though this has already gotten the "approved answer", it turns out that there is this [AWESOME versions plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) that handles the neverending version maintenance problem.

For those lazy people here are some of its goals:

- **versions:display-dependency-updates** scans a project's dependencies and produces a report of those dependencies which have newer versions available.
- **versions:display-plugin-updates** scans a project's plugins and produces a report of those plugins which have newer versions available.
- **versions:display-property-updates** scans a projectand produces a report of those properties which are used to control artifact versions and which properies have newer versions available.
- **versions:update-parent** updates the parent section of a project so that it references the newest available version. For example, if you use a corporate root POM, this goal can be helpful if you need to ensure you are using the latest version of the corporate root POM.
- **versions:update-properties** updates properties defined in a project so that they correspond to the latest available version of specific dependencies. This can be useful if a suite of dependencies must all be locked to one version.
- **versions:update-child-modules** updates the parent section of the child modules of a project so the version matches the version of the current project. For example, if you have an aggregator pom that is also the parent for the projects that it aggregates and the children and parent versions get out of sync, this mojo can help fix the versions of the child modules. (Note you may need to invoke Maven with the -N option in order to run this goal if your project is broken so badly that it cannot build because of the version mis-match).
- **versions:lock-snapshots** searches the pom for all -SNAPSHOT versions and replaces them with the current timestamp version of that -SNAPSHOT, e.g. -20090327.172306-4
- **versions:unlock-snapshots** searches the pom for all timestamp locked snapshot versions and replaces them with -SNAPSHOT.
- **versions:set** can be used to set the project version from the command line.
- **versions:use-releases** searches the pom for all -SNAPSHOT versions which have been released and replaces them with the corresponding release version.
- **versions:use-next-releases** searches the pom for all non-SNAPSHOT versions which have been a newer release and replaces them with the next release version.
- **versions:use-latest-releases** searches the pom for all non-SNAPSHOT versions which have been a newer release and replaces them with the latest release version.
- **versions:use-next-snapshots** searches the pom for all non-SNAPSHOT versions which have been a newer -SNAPSHOT version and replaces them with the next -SNAPSHOT version.
- **versions:use-latest-snapshots** searches the pom for all non-SNAPSHOT versions which have been a newer -SNAPSHOT version and replaces them with the latest -SNAPSHOT version.
- **versions:use-next-versions** searches the pom for all versions which have been a newer version and replaces them with the next version.
- **versions:use-latest-versions** searches the pom for all versions which have been a newer version and replaces them with the latest version.

Comment: Thanks @Pat for sharing the info about this great Maven plugin!

Comment: This plugin is what I wanted but you might want to first run `mvn --version` and make sure your pom.xml specifies something like ` <prerequisites><maven>3.3.9</maven></prerequisites>` so it doesn't download the Internet.

Comment: I used `<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
      </plugin>
` inside my `pom.xml` After running `mvn versions:display-plugin-updates` I don't get any reference to `maven-clean-plugin` . At https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-clean-plugin I see the last version is `3.1.0` . Is it a bug? Am I missing something?

Comment: Easy way to get everything you just typed out is to run `mvn -Dplugin=versions help:describe`

Comment: This looks helpful but why do I get: "Could not load specified rules from file /path/to/project/src/etc/versions-rules.xml" when I run this?

Answer (score 9):

How the version of a plugin is selected, along with discussion about the plugin versions in the superpom is covered in detail [here](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Plugin-Versions-in-the-Super-pom-td208080.html).

Actually the currently selected answer isn't quite right. It should be

```xml
<project>
  <build>
   <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I explained why [here](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/05/optimal-maven-plugin-configuration/):

"The regular plugins section also allows the version and default configuration to be defined, and this is where the confusion lies. It is technically valid to define the plugin version and default configuration here, but I find it easier to grok the pom when following this guideline:

If the plugin block is not defining an execution (and thus binding maven to do something in the lifecycle), put that block in pluginManagment"

Comment: You should put the information (or at least a summary) of the links as said in the help, "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: This should be better

Answer (score 3):

Some maven plugins are restricted to maven versions.  For example, generally projects around here use Maven 2.0.4, which is restricted to use the war plugin 2.0.2 - this works with overlays.  The 2.1-alpha whatever, however, that Maven 2.0.9 uses, does not - so we had to manually downgrade.  Maven, unless otherwise instructed, will attempt to use the latest version of a plugin that it can according to its version.